# Get last 4 characters of every element of array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, substring

I would be surprised if this hasn't been asked in the past. I was unable to find something that works. I have an array of strings and I would like to create a new array with only the last 4 characters of each of the elements. The code is below. What do I need to change to make it work?

```
for(i=0; i<userScanDataObjects.length;i++){
        // if statement used to select every alternative element from the array as th rows are duplicated
        if (i%2 !==0){
            deviceID_raw.push(userScanDataObjects[i].deviceID.value);
            deviceID.push(deviceID_raw[i].substring(5,8));

    }
```

Comment: Without seeing the data, I can't point out *all* possible problems, but using `i` to access `deviceID_raw` is going to be a problem. You're only accessing even members of `userScanDataObjects`, but pushing a single object onto `deviceID_raw` each time. From the second object (`i == 2`) on, `i` will be past the end of `deviceID_raw`. (`i == 0` pushes to `deviceID_raw[0]`; `i == 2` pushes to `deviceID_raw[1]`; etc.)

Comment: `"".match.call(arr, /\w{4}$[?,]/g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.map` depending on your targeted browser support/polyfills. And you can do the following:

```
for( var i = 0; i < array.length; ++ i ) {
  array[i] = array[i].substr(-4);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
['11114444', '22224444'].map(function(string) { return string.substring(string.length - 4, string.length) })
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't work for me. Thank you for the answer though. Also, for anyone else reading this, I might have made an error in implementing the code. Please try this out and see if it works for you.